# How to store the response from rest call in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a rest call where it gives some response.I need to  capture only regno and time from that response.Right now Im storing in a variable as

```
var response;
response= response + (regno ? regno : "UNKNOWN") + source.datetime.
replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/Z/, '') + "<br>";
```

Such that result is displayed in mail as below .when i use window.pstMsg({body:response,subject:"Reg Data"}, "*");

```
50073105  2017-02-15 11:45:49.076
50072921  2017-02-15 10:42:51.040
50000291  2017-02-15 09:48:58.168
50073185  2017-02-15 09:27:50.869
```

But I want to display in table format.So I want to capture that response in array type .so that I can display each array in one row.How can we do this ,can someone help.

Comment: You can use the Array object in javascript. var responses = new Array();
var data = (regno ? regno : "UNKNOWN") + source.datetime.
replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/Z/, '') + "<br>";
reponses.push(data);

Comment: @ChennaiCoder how I could forget this..Thanks

Comment: @ChennaiCoder Now I want to display this in table form.Iam trying this

Comment: window.pstMsg({body:"<html><table><tr><th>Request</th></tr><tr>" + response[i] + "</tr></table></html>",subject:"New ID"}, "*");    How can i iterate each array object in one <tr>?

Comment: var a = new Array();
a.push('aasdg'); a.push('basdg');

for (x in a){
console.log(a[x]);
}

Comment: var responses = new Array();
var msg ='';
responses.push('50073105  2017-02-15 11:45:49.076 </br>');
responses.push('50072921  2017-02-15 10:42:51.040 </br>');


//create a msg out of response
for (index in responses){
 msg = msg + responses[index];
}


//add msg to the body
var bodytext = "<html><table><tr><th>Request</th></tr><‌​tr>" + msg + "</tr></table></html>"
alert(bodytext);
window.pstMsg({body:bodytext,subject:"New ID"}, "*");