# How to form a json array from the response coming from rest call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I got a response from a rest call and such that (Ref ? Ref : "UNKNOWN"),source.datetime.replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/Z/, '') and source.status_code have the respective response values.This is in one if loop and I consoled this in a variable and it displays as

```
var data = (Ref ?Ref : "UNKNOWN") +  source.datetime.replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/Z/, '') +source.status_code ;

In logs i get as
dataaaaa 50073151 2017-02-24 16:14:41.203200 OK
dataaaaa 50005230 2017-02-24 15:40:46.190200 OK
dataaaaa 50073481 2017-02-24 09:16:14.885200 OK
```

Now I have a array as

```
var content = '{Ref":"","createdTime":"","responseCode":""}'
```

So I want to store above response as json object as

```
{{Ref":"50073151","createdTime":"2017-02-24 16:14:41.203","responseCode":"200 OK"},{Ref":
"50005230","createdTime":"2017-02-24 15:40:46.190","responseCode":"200 OK"},{Ref":
"50073481","createdTime":"2017-02-24 09:16:14.885","responseCode":"200 OK"}}
```

How can we get this..can some help me in this..Thanks!

Comment: Since you have not accepted the answer but just upvoted, did it solve your problem?

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed Ive added the comment.Not solved completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a space here

```
var data = (Ref ?Ref : "UNKNOWN") +  source.datetime.replace(/T/, '').replace(/Z/, '') +' '+source.status_code ;
```

then split the data into an array

```
var JSONArr=[];

var arr = data.split(' ');
var obj={"Ref":arr[0],"createdTime":arr[1],"responseCode":arr[2]};
JSONArr.push(obj);
```

You need to loop the last 3 lines. Also since you have space in your data itself like date, you may want to split it in some other character, but you get the point.

Comment: ...Thanks for ur help..It worked partially.The way json is getting consoled is {Ref":"50073151","createdTime":"2017-02-24 16:14:41.203","responseCode":"200 OK"},{Ref":
"50005230","createdTime":"2017-02-24 15:40:46.190","responseCode":"200 OK"} only one json object at  a time.On what condition can we  add the loop so to get as one array..Am bit confused.Any help would be very useful to me @sharjeel

Comment: JSONArr is the array with all the elements. You need to put the loop only in the last 3 lines. Please paste your code in jsfiddle, save it and send me the link

Comment: ok..no problem if u cant join..I'll send to the fiddle hope it would understand

Comment: sorry was out, can join now

Comment: can u join now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136760/discussion-between-user7350714-and-sharjeel-ahmed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: can you link me to your other questions so that i can answer them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444015/how-to-store-the-response-from-rest-call-in-an-array-in-javascript